# Relation between F-norm and 2-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

From the definition of 2-norm, $\||A|\|_2 = sup_{\|x\|_2 = 1} \||A|x\|_2$.

Since F-norm is equal to 2-norm of vector we have that, $\||A|\|_2 = sup_{\|x\|_2 = 1} \||A|x\|_2 = sup_{\|x\|_F = 1} \||A|x\|_F = sup_{\|x\|_F = 1} \|Ax\|_F$, right?

Comment: Yes, but this says nothing about the relationship between the frobenius and l2 operator norm

Comment: Its true but straight from the definition?